# How can I use controller as a string?

Tags: string, flutter, dart, texteditingcontroller

I want to pass the controller as a String in an argument but the controller is of TextEditingController type. How can I change the type of controller as a String?

Comment: `TextEditingController.text` ?

Comment: You want the data of texteditingcontroller or controller itself. If you want controller data simply pass texteditingcontroller.text

Comment: thanks, it worked!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access the `text` property.

```
TextEditingController.text
```

Replace it with your controller's name. i.e

```
usernameController.text
```